# Auto dialer on Windows Phone 8.1/Windows phone 8.1 silver light

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

We can make a call by using below piece of code.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";

phoneCallTask.Show();
```

But my requirement is to automate dialing.Above piece of code requires manual intervention to hit/select call button for dialing. Is there any way that i can simulate dial event on windows phone so calls will automated. If there is no such support on windows phone 8, some scripting language does the job for me?

Answer (score 0):

No, using this task is only way on Windows Phone how you can begin phone call.

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows Phone does not support it. You need to have user consent to start a call/send SMS as there may be charges associated with these actions.